# How to run camera dependent program on android Emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I made a few programs in which I need to capture pictures using notebook Camera and send it through email. THe problem is neither can I send an email nor I can capture pictures using camera through emulator. I have gone through some suggested solutions like "tomgibara" but like most of the people it is not working for me in case of camera. And I havent found any solution of sending email thorugh emulaotr cuz there is not option. I don't have android device to run these programs on that. Is there any way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

On my emulator, you can't use Camera or send mail, you'll either have to test it on the phone, tablet or something with android (Not emulator).  with debug mode on, or just presume it works...